# Stop Socket IO event firing same number of times it's called

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have an Ionic/AngularJS app that emits an event in a function to my Node server like so:

```
  $scope.doKeywordSearch = function (keyword, details) {
    var lat = details.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = details.geometry.location.lng();
    socket.emit('keywordSearch', {lat: lat, lng: lng, keyword: keyword});
    socket.on('searchResults', function (results) {
      console.log(results);
    });
  }
```

On the server, the event is handled like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('keywordSearch', function(searchData) {
    var searchResults = [];
    function(){
      //do loads of search stuff here
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      socket.emit('searchResults', {results: searchResults});
    },2000)
  })
});
```

And the searchResults event on the client is handled like this:

```
socket.on('searchResults', function (results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

For every time I call the function, the results are returned the same number of times I have called the function before while the Node app is running, + 1. So it increments each time.

How can I stop this happening, and have it returned once per each time I call the function?
Are there errors in the way I have structured the Socket.io events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you call `doKeywordSearch` you add another listener by calling

```
socket.on('searchResults', function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Make sure you only call `socket.on('searchResults'...` once after your app is loaded.